# How do I remove an email domain value and add a new one in a column - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, split, concatenation

So I have a bunch of users in a column that get refreshed as:

```
Bill@test.comXYZ
Tom@test.comXYZ
John@test.comXYZ
```

We refresh the database each week and I need to update these appropriate emails to:

```
Bill@domain.com
Tom@domain.com
John@domain.com
```

I figured I can use concat to do the latter, but I am stuck on the former issue. Is there a way to split the values (like split Bill@test.comXYZ into Bill - @test.comXYZ and then remove the @TEXT values?).

Anyways, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mySQL replace function, i.e.

```
 UPDATE mytable
    set myfield = replace (myfield, '@test.comXYZ', 'domain.com')
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace